# Como alterar delimitador de decimal no gráfico do primfaces?

Tags: java, primefaces

Estou com um problema que o meu delimitador de decimal no [componente de gráfico do primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml) está configurado para ser `.`, como eu faço para alterar para `,`?

Comment: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=88846 sugeriram usar um custom extender para isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer a modificação é necessário criar um método no javascript que faça a mudança dos decimais:

```
function formatChart() {
    $.jqplot.sprintf.thousandsSeparator = '.';
    $.jqplot.sprintf.decimalMark = ','; 
}
```

Depois associar essa função de extensão ao gráfico criado pelo java:

```
chartModel = new BarChartModel(); 
chartModel.setExtender("formatChart");
```